# get option framework options returns Call to undefined function of_get_option()

Tags: theme-options, options

I have this kind of twitter feeds fetcher and as the twitter API requires consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret so I created those fields using option framework in my theme and then created a config file (config.php) to used for the twitters api

```
define('CONSUMER_KEY', of_get_option("enable_tw") && of_get_option("tw_consumer_key") ? of_get_option("tw_consumer_key") : 'assume my consumer key here' );
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', of_get_option("enable_tw") && of_get_option("tw_consumer_secret") ? of_get_option("tw_consumer_secret") : 'assume my consumer secret key here' );

// User Access Token
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', of_get_option("enable_tw") && of_get_option("tw_access_token") ? of_get_option("tw_access_token") : 'assume my access token key here' );
define('ACCESS_SECRET', of_get_option("enable_tw") && of_get_option("tw_access_secret") ? of_get_option("tw_access_secret") : 'assume my access secret key' );
```

but it gives me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   of_get_option() in
>   C:\wamp64\www\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\Axada\js\twfeed\api\config.php on line 6

any ideas, help please how to access and retrieved those values from the specific option framework fields?

note: config.php is located on

> my_theme/js/twfeed/api/

and loaded using

```
require_once('config.php'); // Path to config file
```

you can check the [script twetter js here](http://axada.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Axada/js/twfeed/tweetie.js)

Comment: well, the error speaks for itself, but for a more specific explanation  you will need to explain when and how you load that config

Comment: please see my updated post, I have added an info about how I load the config.php

Comment: you should never access directly files in the theme folder which is most likely what you do. write proper wordpress ajax

Comment: im not using ajax in there

Comment: obviously you are, otherwise you would not get the error. alternatively edit the question and this time supply **all** the relevant details :(

Comment: I don't know what to do anymore on how to fix this error and retrieved the option frameworks option value as first of all, im not the author of this twitter script. :(